# get badge text that set before in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can set a badge text in chrome extension by below api

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: '<number_of_new_teets>'});
```

How can I get the badge text that I have set before ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`chrome.browserAction.getBadgeText`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-getBadgeText):

```
chrome.browserAction.getBadgeText({}, function(result) {
    alert('Badge text = ' + result);
});
```

This method (like most of the Chrome extension API) is asynchronous, so you need to specify a callback function that receives the result.

Comment: I am getting following error when I use your code  `Uncaught Error: Invocation of form browserAction.getBadgeText(function) doesn't match definition browserAction.getBadgeText(object details, function callback) extensions`

Answer (score 0):

[Answer by Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20686496/6908282) is returning blank `result` for all tabs. Adding `tab.id` worked for me:

```js
chrome.browserAction.getBadgeText({ tabId: activeTab.id }, result => {
    alert('Badge text = ' + result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome extension API v3, the chrome.browserAction API has been replaced with the chrome.action API.

To set the badge text:

```
chrome.action.setBadgeText({text: '<number_of_new_tweets>'});
```

To get the badge text:

```
chrome.action.getBadgeText({}, function(result) {
  var badgeText = result;
  console.log("Badge text: " + badgeText);
});
```

The usage is similar to the v2 API, but note that chrome.action is used instead of chrome.browserAction in Chrome extension API v3.